# Get caret position when key pressed using KeyboardFocusManager

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, keyboardfocusmanager

I'm trying to get the current caret position when the "<" character is typed, using a KeyboardFocusManager. Code below. If the text field is empty when they character is typed I would expect the caret position to be 0. However, the result I actually get is this: 0   0   1. Could anyone explain why this is happening?

```
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;


public class TextEditor {

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class TextClass extends JTextArea {

        static int startpos = 0; 

        public boolean checkKeyTyped (KeyEvent e) {
            String keystr = Character.toString(e.getKeyChar());
            switch (keystr) {
                case "<":
                    startpos = getSelectionStart();
                    System.out.print("   " + startpos);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }       

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        final JTextArea textArea = new TextClass();
        frame.add(textArea);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // Add keyboard listener

        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
                return ((TextClass) textArea).checkKeyTyped(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: DocumentListener & Caret

Answer (score 0):

You are using a general Key Event dispatcher. The possible events are `KEY_PRESSED`, `KEY_TYPED` and `KEY_RELEASED`. Based on what you say, you need `KEY_TYPED`. So filter for that:

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
                return ((TextClass) textArea).checkKeyTyped(e);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not how you are supposed to do it, you are supposed to implement a [`KeyListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) and add it to your `JTextArea` using [`addKeyListener(KeyListener)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addKeyListener-java.awt.event.KeyListener-), as next:

```
final JTextArea textArea = new TextClass();
...
textArea.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(final KeyEvent e) {
        char key = e.getKeyChar();
        switch (key) {
            case '<':
                System.out.print("   " + textArea.getSelectionStart());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(final KeyEvent e) {
    }
});
```

Up to now, you get it printed 3 times because your method is called for each type of `KeyEvent` that is triggered whenever you type on a key:

#### `KEY_TYPED`

> The "`key typed`" event.  This event is generated when a character is
>   entered.  In the simplest case, it is produced by a single key press.
>   Often, however, characters are produced by series of key presses, and
>   the mapping from key pressed events to key typed events may be
>   many-to-one or many-to-many.

#### `KEY_PRESSED`

> The "`key pressed`" event. This event is generated when a key is pushed
>   down.

#### `KEY_RELEASED`

> The "`key released`" event. This event is generated when a key is let
>   up.